# push notification not being received in iOS using topics in firebase (FCM)

Tags: php, android, ios, objective-c, iphone

when i am trying to send push notifications manually from fire base console the push notification is well received but when i am trying to send notification from the server side no push had beed received here is my code inside **appdelegate**

**appdelegate.h**

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//  lechef
//
//  Created by Zakaria Darwish on 9/5/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 CodeBee. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "constant.h"
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import "MPGNotification.h"
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#include "constant.h"
@import UserNotifications;
@import GoogleMaps;
@import GooglePlaces;
@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseInstanceID;
@import FirebaseMessaging;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;


@end
```

and the code used in **appdelegate.m**

```
  //
//  AppDelegate.m
//  lechef
//
//  Created by Zakaria Darwish on 9/5/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 CodeBee. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
@import UserNotifications;
@import GoogleMaps;
@import GooglePlaces;
@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseInstanceID;
@import FirebaseMessaging;


@interface AppDelegate () 
{
    MPGNotification *notification;
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
        // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
        UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
        | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
        | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
         requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
         completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
         }
         ];

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        [[FIRMessaging messaging] setRemoteMessageDelegate:self];
  #endif
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    [UINavigationBar appearance].backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:blackRedColor green:blackGreenColor blue:blackBlueColor alpha:ALFA];

    self.window.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:greenRedColor green:greenGreenColor blue:greenBlueColor alpha:ALFA];
    [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"******************************"];
    float ver = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:blackRedColor green:blackGreenColor blue:blackBlueColor alpha:ALFA]];

    if(ver >= 8 && ver<=9)
    {
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

        }
    }else if (ver >=9){

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];


    }
    else{
        //iOS6 and iOS7 specific code
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];

    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                 name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
    [FIRApp configure];
    [self connectToFcm];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:@"/topics/news"];
    return YES;
}



// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
    // Print message ID.
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}

// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    // Print full message
    NSLog(@"%@", [remoteMessage appData]);
}
#endif


- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
    // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
    // should be done.
    NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"isTokenInserted"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:@"/topics/news"];

}


-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{


    // NSDictionary *newUserInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"notification"];


    UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];

    if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground || state == UIApplicationStateInactive)
    {
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.userInfo = userInfo;
        localNotification.alertTitle = [userInfo objectForKey:@"title"];
        localNotification.alertBody = [userInfo objectForKey:@"body"];
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    }



    else if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {


        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1054);
        UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderimage"];
        NSString *title  = [userInfo objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *body = [userInfo objectForKey:@"body"];


        notification = [MPGNotification notificationWithTitle:title subtitle:body backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:blackRedColor green:greenGreenColor blue:greenBlueColor alpha:ALFA] iconImage:icon];
        notification.duration = 5.0;
        notification.swipeToDismissEnabled = NO;
        [notification show];




    }




}



-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"content---%@", token);
}



- (void)connectToFcm {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
        }
    }];
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

and here is my php script that i am using:
**PHP script**

```
<php?
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=***************************


{
  "to": "/topics/news",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: One thing to note: Your opening php tag should be `<?php` not `<php?`.

Comment: i fixed what next